# Horizontal RelativeLayout android

Tags: android, layout, screen-orientation

How can I set **just one** activity or **just one** RelativeLayout from an android application to **always** have horizontal orientation?

I have tried to add ***android:screenOrientation = "horizontal"***
and ***android:screenOrientation = "landscape"*** to the RelativeLayout but it has no effect.

Thank you.

Comment: Use LinearLayout instead!?

Answer (score 2):

**RelativeLayout** does not have orientations! Maybe you need to use **LinearLayout**